# wp_head loads into body tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and this morning I have noticed that `wp_head()` outputs content into `body` tag.

Here is the code of `header.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
        <script>(function() {
            var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
            if (!_fbq.loaded) {
            var fbds = document.createElement('script');
            fbds.async = true;
            fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
            _fbq.loaded = true;
           }
           _fbq.push(['addPixelId', 'xxx']);
          })();
          window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
          window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
        </script>
        <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"                    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxx&amp;ev=NoScript" /></noscript>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           /* <![CDATA[ */
           var google_conversion_id = xxxx;
           var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
           var google_remarketing_only = true;
           /* ]]> */
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <div style="display:inline;">
            <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/xxxx/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
            </div>
        </noscript>

       <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="site-branding col-sm-4">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Logo-nov-.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a></h1>

            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 mainmenu">
        <div class="mobilenavi"></div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'submenu', 'theme_location' => 'primary','container_class' => 'topmenu','menu_id'=>'topmenu' ,'menu_class'=>'sfmenu' ) ); ?>
        </div>

        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->


<?php if( is_page_template('homepage.php') ){ get_template_part( 'inc/feature' ); } ?>

<div id="content" class="site-content ">
```

I have tried removing remarketing tags, but makes no difference. Also I have tried disabling all plugins, and still no go

Comment: How do you know that wp_head() is outputting content into the body? (I'd also suspect that bit of `<noscript>` with the `img` in it: you wouldn't want that in a `<head>`, I'd say... That may be causing a browser to restructure the DOM in memory so that it doesn't end up with an invalid element in the `head`. It seems likely that the Facebook code, i.e. both the script and no script, was written to be put in the body, probably just before the closing `</body>`.)

Comment: is there any issue or error you are facing after this

Comment: I have tried removing retargeting code with `noscript` tag, but it doesn't make a difference. Also I know it is `wp_head` because everything after last `noscript` tag goes to `body`

Comment: That may not mean that wp_head is causing the problem. A browser will attempt to rearrange invalid HTML to make it valid in memory. So, basically, when it first encounters an element that's invalid in `head`, like an `img` element, it'll close the `head` and start the `body` instead. So it's possible that it's something before wp_head that's causing the issue. You need to examine the actual HTML output for errors, not look at the PHP, to find out what's causing the problem. Try running the site through http://validator.w3.org and looking at the first few problems it finds, too.

Comment: (And bear in mind that what I mean is that you're probably looking at the page source using a browser inspector that shows you the DOM in memory after the browser has fixed it, not the true page source, which will probably be in a different order. In Chrome, for example, compare the difference between using the Web Inspector and View->Developer->View Page Source, which will show you the actual output code before the browser's processed it.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so according to Matt Gibson comment, I have found the solution. Not the perfect one, but it is a solution that works.

I have moved `wp_head()` up, right after `<link rel="pingback">...` ant it works now.

Comment: But that doesn't pinpoint the culprit... which would be one of the scripts, I suppose...

Comment: Actually it is often plugin called `Social Sharing Toolkit`. When I switch that one with e.g. `Tweet like plusone` it works fine